# How to write in .csv file from a generator in python

Tags: python, csv, generator

My Generator looks like the following:

```
def mygen(reader):
    for row in reader:
        yield row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]
```

I'm trying to insert these generator produced values in the following manner:

```
file1=open(f2,"w")
writes=csv.writer(file1,delimiter=' ',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
g=mygen(reader)
for x in g:
    writes.writerow([x])
```

It enters blank rows to the file without producing any output.
It works perfectly when I use the same generator to insert code to a table.

Comment: It wouldn't add blank rows; are you saying *no rows at all* are added? Make sure you haven't used `reader` separately before using it in `mygen()`.

Comment: That's exactly what happened. I used it earlier as well. Thanks so much. But please tell me why the reason?

Comment: File objects have a file pointer, which tracks where to read from or write to next. Each time you read some data, that pointer moves forward. Once you have read all data, it'll be at the end of the file and further attempts to read return no data (unless you were to add to the file).

Comment: So unless you reopen the file or set the file pointer back to the start, you won't see more data when you try to read from it, even through a `csv.reader()` object. You can see what byte the pointer is at with `fileobj.tell()`, and move it with `fileobj.seek()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `x` is already a sequence, you don't need to wrap it in a list:

```
for x in g:
    writes.writerow(x)
```

You could just  pass your generator directly to `writes.writerows()`:

```
with open(f2, "w") as file1:
    writes = csv.writer(file1, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writes.writerows(mygen(reader))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import csv
>>> def mygen(reader):
...     for row in reader:
...         yield row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]
...
>>> reader = csv.reader('''\
... foo,bar,baz,spam,ham,eggs
... 42,81,13,97,73,100
... '''.splitlines())
>>> writes = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
>>> writes.writerows(mygen(reader))
"foo" "bar" "baz" "spam" "ham"
"42" "81" "13" "97" "73"
```

You do need to watch out that your `reader` is not a generator you already exhausted. If it is a `csv.reader()` object, and you read all rows before, you'll need to re-wind the underlying file object back to the start with `fileobj.seek(0)`. It'd be better to avoid reading the file twice, however.

If your `reader` object produces sequences (such as lists or tuples), you could just use slicing to get the first 5 elements, no need to type out every single index:

```
def mygen(reader):
    for row in reader:
        yield row[:5]
```

Comment: @ParisaRai: given a *fresh* `reader` object producing rows the code works just fine.